# www to non-www 301 redirect doesn't work

Tags: htaccess, cpanel

I am redirecting 301 in cpanel www to non-www (naked domain) and the code Cpanel redirect generates doesn't do anything when www to non-www is set.

Server Type:
(Litespeed Server, domain has "Let's encrypt" certificate.)

- DNS config is (not pointing www to non-www as CNAME)
- both point to same IP
- mydomain.dev - A Record - 127.0.0.1
- www.mydomain.dev - A Record - 127.0.0.1

Non-www to www - works

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.dev$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/www\.mydomain\.dev\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

**Www to non-www - doesn't work**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.dev$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/mydomain\.dev\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work" exactly? Are you getting an error? A redirect loop? Nothing at all? "mydomain.dev - A Record - 127.0.0.1" - Is this really pointing to 127.0.0.1? Is your domain really a `.dev` TLD?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
> RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.dev$
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/mydomain\.dev\/$1" [R=301,L]
> ```

This isn't a plain "www to non-www" redirect, it looks like you are also attempting to redirect HTTP to HTTPS (which you make no mention of in your question).

For an ordinary www to non-www redirect, you need to remove the first two conditions (like your earlier redirect that "works"). For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.dev$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/mydomain\.dev\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

However, you can tidy this up by removing the plethora of unnecessary backslash escapes in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* (typical cPanel). For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.dev
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https://mydomain.dev/$1" [R=301,L]
```

I also removed the `$` on the end of the preceding *CondPattern* - in order to catch a potentially FQDN.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing. (Preferably test with 302 - temporary - redirects to avoid caching issues.)

Comment: Yes, I forgot to explicitly mention that I was redirecting to https as well in all cases with or without https and www I wanted it to land on naked https domain.
What I mean by doesn't work is it simply doesn't redirect but stays to url you manually enter, except it did redirect http to https but www remained.

Comment: "redirecting to https as well in all cases _with or without https_" - OK, but the above would be incorrect if that is what you were trying to do as it "attempts" to redirect HTTP only. But where did you get `X-Forwarded-SSL` from? Were you advised to check this header by your host? Otherwise this looks like an error... you should never need to check both `%{HTTPS}` _and_ `%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL}`. (?)

Comment: It was a Cpanel generated code. I'm not sure why it did that way. But looks like it's not reliable in all circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

**Try as follows.
WITHOUT www (all visits go to `https://example.com`):**

```
#start
RewriteEngine On
# non www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
# https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: @dan thank you for clarification

Comment: I've fixed the original code by adding [OR]  
`RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]  
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.dev$  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/mydomain\.dev\/$1" [R=301,L]`

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @ManfredvonRichthofen That is not strictly correct. Either `HTTPS` is always "off", in which case the check is redundant or the check for `HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL` is redundant and you are allowing malicious requests to block your HTTP to HTTPS redirect. (?)

Comment: Good to hear that! Regards!